# Prove that lower bounds of upper bounds of a subset is a closure operator on a lattice.

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $(L, \le)$ be a poset regarded as a lattice (s.t. $\forall a, b \in L$ both $sup(\{a,b\})$ and $inf(\{a,b\})$ exist in L).

Let $A \subseteq L$. We denote 
$$U(A):= \{ b\in L |  \forall a\in A: a \leq b\} \\
  L(A):= \{ b\in L |  \forall a\in A: b \leq a\}$$

sets of all upper and lower bounds of $A$.

I need to prove that map $C(A):= L(U(A))$ defines a closure operator on $L$.
That is I need to prove 3 properties:

**1)**  $A\subseteq C(A)$

**2)** $C(C(A)) = C(A)$

**3)** $A\subseteq B \implies C(A) \subseteq C(B)$

**My try:**

1) $b\in A \implies \forall a\in U(A): b\leq a \implies b \in L(U(A)) \implies A \subseteq L(U(A)) = C(A)$

2) ?

3) We have property: $A \subseteq B \implies U(B) \subseteq U(A)$  and $L(B) \subseteq L(A)$.

Thus 
$ A\subseteq B \implies U(B) \subseteq U(A) \implies L(U(A)) \subseteq L(U(B))$

I'm strugling to prove idempotency property. I guess to prove it I need to show that $$U(A) = U(L(U(A)))$$ but I don't know how to do it formally.

**Question: are these proofs valid and how do I prove idempotency?**

**Edit:**

2) $U(L(U(A))) \subseteq U(A)$ from properties (1) and (3).
$$a \in U(A) \implies \forall b \in L(U(A)): b \leq a \implies a \in U(L(U(A))) \implies U(A) \subseteq U(L(U(A)))$$
That is equality holds, thus $C$ is idempotent.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Your proofs look valid to me. Using what you showed in part 1, you can conclude that $U(A)\subseteq U(L(U(A)))$, so only the reverse inclusion is needed. Then you can just ask yourself if you can have $a\in U(A)$ such that $a\notin U(L(U(A)))$. In other words, can there be $b\in L(U(A))$ such that $a\ngeq b$?

Comment: @KevinLong Isn't it backwards from part 1: $A \subseteq C(A) \implies U(C(A)) \subseteq U(A)$ and not the other way around? Because upper/lower bounds of superset are definitely upper/lower bounds of each subset bot not the other way.

Comment: Sorry, that's right. I was thinking the right thing, but wrote the wrong one. Everything after that still explains what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kevin Long wrote in a comment, you already have that $U(A) \subseteq U(L(U(A)))$.
For the converse inclusion, using (1), and your observation that $A \subseteq B$ implies $U(B) \subseteq U(A)$,
$$A \subseteq L(U(A)) \Longrightarrow U(L(U(A))) \subseteq U(A).$$
Notice also that this is true for any poset, which is quite clear since nowhere in the proof is any lattice property used.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on the first step?
$b \in U(A) \implies \forall a \in A: a\leq b \implies ... ?... \implies b \in U(L(U(A)))$
I don't fully get what arguments should be applied here.

Comment: Figured it out by myself, thanks.